# Why I can't add comments anymore?

Tags: support, comments, privileges

A few days ago, I was able to add comments below questions. But today, I'm not able to do that anymore. Why has this changed, and how can I get back the ability to post comments?

Comment: Where? On Server Fault?

Comment: No, on Stackoverflow

Comment: Ah, okay. You haven't associated this account with your account on Stack Overflow, so it isn't [displayed in your profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/167918/spc?tab=accounts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commenting is [a privilege available only to users with a reputation score of 50 or more](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Most likely, you previously had 50 reputation and thus the ability to post comments, but you've since lost reputation and have dropped below the 50 point minimum threshold. As for what could cause you to lose that many points, there are a couple of possibilities. Some of your posts (questions and answers) might have been downvoted, or you might have had an answer flagged by the community as spam.

However, note that you are always allowed (regardless of reputation) to post comments on your *own* questions and answers to your *own* questions. You only have to have 50+ reputation to post comments on *other people's* questions. So this may be simply a matter of where you're trying to post said comments—either on your own questions or on someone else's question.

Comment: That's probably not the same case here on meta? As I'm able to comment here.

Comment: @spc: Read the last paragraph of my answer. You're allowed to comment on your own questions and answers to your own questions.  Commenting on *other* people's questions is a privilege that must be earned.

Comment: I see now. I'd like to associate my Stackoverflow account with meta but honestly I'm not sure how, all other stachexchange accounts have been associated with meta except stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough reputation on any account associated with the one you posted this question from.  Do you have another registered account with more than 50 reputation?

Or, maybe you were only commenting on answers to your own questions?  You're always able to do that, even with only 1 reputation.

Comment: I have reputation 38 at the moment there, this is a coupled account

Comment: @spc: I don't see Stack Overflow in your [associated accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/167918/spc?tab=accounts), but 38 wouldn't be enough to comment.  You may have lost reputation recently due to downvotes or question/answer deletion.

Comment: I had reputation of 6 and I was able to comment at the moment, then one of my posts has been marked for deletion as it was more for programmers.stackexchange.com than for stackoverflow etc.. May I've lost commenting privileges that way

Comment: @spc: See my edit.  I think you were just commenting on answers to your own questions, which you're always able to do.  Like you're doing here.

Comment: I'm able to add comments here on every post. You might be right for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You are only allowed to post comments anywhere once you have 50 reputation, so if you were previously able to post comments, this can happen for two reasons:

1. You were previously commenting on your own question, or on answers to your own question. This is always allowed.
2. You used to have more than 50 rep but lost some due to downvotes. Privileges such as [posting comments anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) depend on your current reputation, so it is possible to lose privileges you once had.